# dynamically set object value with undefined key

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create an object that has no value on it.

```
for (let i = 0; i < chartyearsale.length; i++) {

    var year = chartyearsale[i].year,
        grp = chartyearsale[i].family,
        qnt = chartyearsale[i].qnt,
        qntsk = chartyearsale[i].qntsk,
        fat = chartyearsale[i].total;

    total[year] = Object.assign({
        [grp]: {
            val1: (total[year][grp].val1 || 0) + val1,
            val2: (total[year][grp].val2 || 0) + val2,
            val3: (total[year][grp].val3 || 0) + val3
        }
    }, total[year]);

}
```

The values "year, group, value1, value2 and value3" are all defined.

I am getting this response:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'grp')
```

I believe this should be done differently:

```
(total[year][grp].val1 || 0)
//should return 0 if undefined, but it breaks the script!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access a nested property that doesn't exist, even if you alternate it with `|| 0` on the right-hand side:

```js
const obj = {};

// Forbidden:
console.log(obj.foo.bar);
```

So doing `total[year][group].val1` fails, because `total` starts out as the empty object. You need

```
val1: (total[year]?.[group]?.val1 ?? 0) + value1,
```

for all three values, to make the nested access safe.

A nicer approach would be, if you're creating the object for the first time:

```
const total = {
    [year]: {
        [group]: {
            val1: value1,
            val2: value2,
            val3: value3,
        }
    }
};
```

If the properties may already exist:

```
total[year] ??= {};
total[year][group] ??= {};
const totalGroup = total[year][group];
totalGroup.val1 = (totalGroup.val1 ?? 0) + value1;
totalGroup.val2 = (totalGroup.val2 ?? 0) + value2;
totalGroup.val3 = (totalGroup.val3 ?? 0) + value3;
```

Comment: Its because i dont know how many “year” and “group” are… thats why i cant set previosly

Comment: What do you mean, you don't know how many there are? An identifier is a (single) identifier, referring to exactly one value, not multiple. If you have an array of properties to iterate over and insert into the object, use array methods or `for..of` to iterate over them.

Comment: i edited to show all my code, i tried to make the question more simple, now the error is gone but it wont increment with new values, just replaces it

Comment: If the properties may already exist, and you're not definitely starting from the empty object, then use the code in the last part of my answer. Your existing approach with the `Object.assign` does not preserve other groups on the object - it replaces it with an entirely new object.

Comment: yeap, (total[year]?.[group]?.val1 ?? 0) approch with pre setting total[year] ??= {};
total[year][group] ??= {}; in the loop seal the deal, you saved my day!